# Search all html tags in other html tags

Tags: html, regex, preg-match

I have a problem with the creation of a regular expression.
Specifically, a regular expression that finds all simple HTML tags (eg. `<B>` `<strong>` `<u>`, etc.), and their contents (subsequent tags with the contents of html tag match).

So far, I created a regular expression ([regex101.com/r/lA0kI1/1](https://regex101.com/r/lA0kI1/1)):

```
(?<html_tag>(?<open>\<(?<tag>\w+)\>))(?<content>(\g<html_tag>)|.*)(?<close>\<\/\k<tag>\>)
```

I would like to get this result (something on this pattern):

```
MATCH 1
html_tag    [0-3]   `<b>`
open        [0-3]   `<b>`
tag         [1-2]   `b`
content     [3-47]  `strong<i>italic</i>and again strong`
close       [47-51] `</b>`

MATCH 2
html_tag    [14-28] `<i>`
open        [14-18] `<i>`
tag         [15-16] `i`
content     [17-24] `italic`
close       [24-28] `</i>`
```

How do I can get the result as above?

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5024519).

Comment: @MattRaines: you can but it isn't the appropriate tool.

Comment: `preg_match_all` won't find matches that are inside matches it has already found. This is largely the expected behaviour. For example, if I did `preg_match_all("[\d+]", "123 456 789", $matches);` I would expect it to match ["123", "456", "789"], not ["123", "12", "23", "1", "2", "3", "456", "45", "56", "4", "5", "6", "789", "78", "89", "7", "8", "9"]. So to find both the <b> and the <i> element in your example you'll most likely want to use an XML parser. What is the actual problem you want to solve with the regex?

Comment: Actually, I wanted a make my own parser bbcodes (present this as "Simple HTML tags" have been better example), but apparently I'll have to use ready-made solutions. Thank you for the clarification.